# Angular 5 list json data

Tags: angular, typescript, angular5

I am trying to list a data that fetched from a server. I use `HttpClient`.

This is a sample data that I get

```
{  
   "__zone_symbol__state":true,
   "__zone_symbol__value":{  
      "response":{  
         "_total":1558,
         "channels":[  
            {  
               "name": "hey",
               "views":109151896,
               "followers":2542307,
               "broadcaster_type":"partner"
            },
            ...
```

My ts file

```
const endpoint = `http://localhost:5000/search?key=${key}`
this.channels  = this.http.get(endpoint).toPromise()
```

My html file should be like this

```
<div *ngFor="let ch of channels">
</div>
```

How do I list channels?

Comment: what is the output you get when you convert it to json? i.e. add .then(res => res.json()); to the toPromise().

Comment: @Aeseir `{ "__zone_symbol__state": 0, "__zone_symbol__value": {} }` Also, I got errors `Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: res.json is not a function` and  `Cannot find a differ supporting object '[object Promise]' of type 'object'. NgFor only supports binding to Iterables such as Arrays.`

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow! No, you don't need the `res.json()` anymore if you are doing the new `HttpClient`. But you are missing the subscribe and since http calls are asynchronous, you can't just assign it to the value.

Comment: Hey @Burak, could you make it to work? I have the same issue with a json list and is just not working. I tried to implement DeborahK solution, but I haven't succeed. Any suggestions are welcome.

Comment: Hey @Probandot. Well, in my case I get my json from my backend. In the backend I was sending raw json file to frontend. To solve that, simply I use like `json.data`. It access `data` in the json file. In your case, it could be different.

Comment: @Burak, thanks for answering. I got the JSON, but I haven't figured out how to parse the list, like in your case with channels. I can access the response and total, but not channels. That is what I am trying to do :) When you got the data, could you do something like data.channels and got the contents of the list?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a quick answer:

```
const endpoint = `http://localhost:5000/search?key=${key}`
this.http.get(endpoint).subscribe(channels => this.channels = channels)
```

You need to subscribe in order to submit the http request. You then provide a callback function in the subscribe and that is where you set your `channels` property.

Best practice, however, is to move your data access into a service.

You can find documentation on how to do that here: https://angular.io/guide/http

And I have a complete code example here: https://github.com/DeborahK/MovieHunter

**Service**

The service would look something like this:

```
@Injectable()
export class MovieService {
    private moviesUrl = './api/movies/movies.json';

    constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

    getMovies(): Observable<IMovie[]> {
        return this.http.get<IMovie[]>(this.moviesUrl);
    }
}
```

**Component**

And the component would look something like this:

```
getMovies(): void {
    this.movieService.getMovies()
        .subscribe(movies => this.movies = movies);
```

Answer (score 0):

You also can use [Angular async PIPE](https://angular.io/api/common/AsyncPipe), which works with both promises and observables. SO, just add it in your HTML:

```
<div *ngFor="let ch of channels | async"><
   ...
/div>
```

You do not need to convert your http request to promise (`this.channels  = this.http.get(endpoint).toPromise()`), but as I already said it will work in both cases:

```
this.channels  = this.http.get(endpoint).toPromise();
// OR
this.channels  = this.http.get(endpoint);
```

I usually mark async variables with `$` suffix:

```
this.channels$  = this.http.get(endpoint);

// HTML
<div *ngFor="let ch of channels$ | async">
  ...
</div>
```

the advantage of using `async` pipe is that you need nor to subscribe neither to unsubscribe to any observable.

I created a stackblitz to play with: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-zfzswr